# Google Cloud Functions latency

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions

I wanted to check out the **feasibility of using a Golang cloud function for real-time processing pub/sub messages**. 
I wrote a simple Go function that calculates the time delta between the unix timestamp in the pub/sub message and the current time:

```
package cloudfunction

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

// PubSubMessage is the payload of a Pub/Sub event.
type PubSubMessage struct {
    Data []byte `json:"data"`
}

// HelloPubSub hellos to the world.
func HelloPubSub(ctx context.Context, m PubSubMessage) error {
    unix := string(m.Data)
    i, err := strconv.ParseInt(unix, 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tm := time.Unix(i, 0)
    tnow := time.Now()
    log.Println("Latency cloud function : ", tnow.Sub(tm))
    return nil
}
```

Subsequently I can deploy the function (I am located in Belgium so I am using europe-west1 region):

```
gcloud functions deploy HelloPubSub --runtime go113 --trigger-topic cloudfunction --region europe-west1
```

And then I publish messages to the pub/sub topic by (I have also ran this from a cloud shell to eliminate my internet speed):

```
gcloud pubsub topics publish cloudfunction --message $(date +"%s")
```

I can image that there will be a cold start of a few seconds, but afterwards I expect the latency to drop significantly to about few hundreds of milliseconds but my test clearly proves me wrong:

[image]

**Does anybody know if these latencies are in the to be expected interval of latencies or am I doing something (very obvious) wrong here?**

Comment: You are measuring the latency of cloud functions *plus the pub/sub latency*.

Comment: @Peter ...plus any latency introduced by the `gcloud pubsub` command, plus clock differences between the two machines.

Comment: "Does anybody know if these latencies are in the to be expected interval of latencies" is not a programming question, it's a cloud infrastructure question. Try ServerFault.